# C++ Square Root with recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

My square root program for some reason gets an answer that is a little off from what it should get for most inputs. I'm not sure why this is. Only certain inputs are wrong. I also get a segmentation fault at then very end after the answer is given and am not sure why that is either.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cfloat>
#include<string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//declare sqroot function calls recursive function newton
double sqroot1(double num );
double newton(double num, double guess);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    for( int i = 0 ; i < argc ; i++)
    {
       cout<<"sqroot("<<argv[i+1]<<") is "<< sqroot1(atoi(argv[i+1]))     <<endl;
    }
}

double newton(double num, double a)
{
    if ((abs(a*a - num) <= FLT_EPSILON))
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        newton(num, (a+num/a)/2 );
    }
}

double sqroot1(double num)
{
    double sqrt = newton(num,num/2);
    return sqrt;
}
```

Comment: Enable all warnings and see what the compiler tells you. And see [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: What are some values that give bad square roots, and what values are you getting for them?

Answer (score 2):

The function has undefined behavior because you forgot to place the return statement

```
double newton(double num, double a)
{


    if ((abs(a*a - num) <= FLT_EPSILON))
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        newton(num, (a+num/a)/2 );
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }


}
```

there must be

```
    return newton(num, (a+num/a)/2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the crash because you try to access `argv[argc]`, which is past the end of the `argv` array.

Your numbers are likely off because you're comparing with `FLT_EPSILON`, which is for `float` values.  `DBL_EPSILON` is used for doubles.  Comparing with either of those is not the right approach for this problem, though.  You need to check against a difference that is scaled relative to your `a` value.

Answer (score 0):

I see two fundamental errors that should be fixed first:

1. Your main function doesn't have a return. You should place `return 0;` at the end of your main function before the last `}`.
2. You are trying to access the `argv[argc]`, which doesn't exist. The last existing element in that array is `argv[argc - 1]`. Try changing your loop statement so that it doesn't try to read in that non-existent part of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to 1201ProgramAlarm's answer, why is the following so bad?

```
if ((abs(a*a - num) <= eps))
```

Let's say eps is 1e-15, a bit bigger than DBL_EPSILON. Well, if `a` is even moderately large (something like 5 or greater) then the unit in the last place ([ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)) of `a*a` is bigger than `eps` and the condition can only be true if `a*a == num`. There's a risk, with rounding, that this won't be reached and you end up with infinite recursion and a crash.

Now let's say that `num` is very small such that for the initial guess

```
abs(num/2*num/2 - num) <= eps
```

So for instance, sqroot1(1e-20) will evaluate

```
abs(1e-40/4 - 1e-20)   <= 1e-15
```

which is true and you will get 5e-21 as the square root of 1e-20. This is atrocious precision.